# Truncate timestamp to custom unit of time in SQL Snowflake

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, truncate

Function `DATE_TRUNC` in Snowflake (Docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html)) allows you to truncate a given timestamp to a given **default unit of time**, being available:

```
 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE' and 'SECOND'
```

As an example:

```
DATE_TRUNC('MINUTE', '2015-05-08T23:39:35.123') --> 2015-05-08T23:39:00.000'
```

How would we do it if we want to truncate a date to a **customize unit of time** as in:

```
 '5 MINUTE' OR '30 SECONDS'
```

As an example these customized times would give:

```
DATE_TRUNC('30 SECONDS', '2015-05-08T23:39:35.123') --> 2015-05-08T23:39:30.000'
DATE_TRUNC('30 SECONDS', '2015-05-08T23:39:15.123') --> 2015-05-08T23:39:00.000'

DATE_TRUNC('5 MINUTES', '2015-05-08T23:39:35.123') --> 2015-05-08T23:35:00.000'
DATE_TRUNC('5 MINUTES', '2015-05-08T23:34:35.123') --> 2015-05-08T23:30:00.000'
```

Is there a workaround or alternative function to get these results?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to [epoch seconds](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html), division, [floor](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/floor.html), multiply

thus for 30 seconds steps:

```
SELECT 
    TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2015-05-08T23:39:35.123') as date
    ,DATE_PART(epoch_second, date) as epoch_sec
    ,floor(epoch_sec / 30) * 30 as epoch_in_30sec_steps
    ,TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(epoch_in_30sec_steps) as time_in_30sec_steps;
```

gives:

| DATE | EPOCH_SEC | EPOCH_IN_30SEC_STEPS | TIME_IN_30SEC_STEPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-05-08 23:39:35.123 | 1431128375 | 1431128370 | 2015-05-08 23:39:30.000 |

and thus 5 minutes is:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(floor(epoch_sec / 300) * 300) as time_in_5min_steps
```

Answer (score 1):

What Simeon said.

You can put it in a nice little UDF like this

```
create or replace function trunc_by_seconds(num_seconds int, t timestamp_ntz(0))
returns timestamp_ntz(0)
as $$ to_timestamp_ntz(num_seconds * floor(date_part(epoch_second, t) / num_seconds))$$;
```

and then just use

```
select trunc_by_seconds(30, ...)
```

Comment: UDF's prevent cache ... so technically yes this works, just worth pointing out this may cost $$ where the cache could provide free results.

Answer (score 0):

[MOD()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mod.html) approach, however the epoch_sec appears more elegant, less verbose and equally efficient.

I just get a kick out of finding alternative solutions :-)

```
SELECT
  TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2015-05-08T23:09:35.023') as date
   ,DATE_TRUNC( 'second',date) some_date_time
   ,TIMESTAMPADD(second, -MOD(DATE_PART (second,some_date_time),30), some_date_time)   as Time_In_30sec_Steps
```

[image]

Rare would be the SQL question be with only one answer.

Comment: hmm, code in code block is more readable, and the results can be pasted into a table or another code block.. But I do love options. Also your picture doesn't show the last result, the important one.. ;-)

Comment: 1000% agree with. As stated in my first sentence 'epoch_sec appears more elegant' .  However as you'd be aware there's about 1000 cool solutions to each problem and if we all just behave like sheep and only look at the most common or pretty solution we'll all be the same.  I want to think of new and fun ways to solve problems - admittedly SO is not the ideal environment for this behaviour - I just hope just 1 person appreciates an alternative solution is cool and learns something. Today that's you.

Comment: sorry, my point was, pasting a picture of code is almost unusable. Please paste it as a code block (surrounded in triple ` )